# I get a chinese character in my txt file when using BufferedWriter and FileWriter. How can I get my integer to write to "caseCountFile" correctly?

Tags: java, encode, cjk

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        String url = "https://www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Pages/Cases.aspx";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements info = doc.getElementsByTag("strong");
        
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("data");
        fw.write(info.toString());
        fw.close();
        
        String caseCount = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("data")).get(2);
        
        String caseCount1 = caseCount.replaceFirst("<strong>", "");
        String caseCount2 = caseCount1.substring(0, caseCount1.length()-9);
        String caseCount3 = caseCount2.replaceAll(",", "");
        
        System.out.println(caseCount3);
        
        int actualCaseCount = Integer.parseInt(caseCount3.toString());

        System.out.println(actualCaseCount);
        
        String oldCaseCount = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("caseCountFile")).get(0);
        int newOldCaseCount = Integer.valueOf(oldCaseCount.toString());
        
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("caseCountFile"));
        bw.write(actualCaseCount);
        bw.flush();
        
        System.out.println(actualCaseCount - newOldCaseCount);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

Is it something to do with how the data I scraped is encoded from the CDC website?  The culprit variable is "actualCaseCount":  When I print it to the console, prints correctly.  When I write it to the txt file, it prints this: "毉"

I'm trying to write the number of total COVID cases in the US from the CDC page to a text file so I can track day to day changes in the data.

Yes, I'm new at this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're writing the actual number to the file (which gets encoded as a number of bytes), instead of the String value of the number.

Try doing

```java
bw.write(actualCaseCount.toString());
```

Or, since it's the same value as `caseCount3` you could do this instead

```java
bw.write(caseCount3);
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  Totally fixed it.  Didn't think to use String instead of int to write to file.  Made my day!